# What is Matrix.getMatrix command?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, int

I have a little problem with understanding a line in a java program I got. The line is:

```
int[][] mat = Matrix.getMatrix();
```

- What is `Matrix.getMarix`?
- What does that mean?

Comment: A static method of `Matrix` class.

Comment: It converts a matrix (of presumably ints) into a 2D array of ints. What's not to understand?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what `Matrix` is this line either:

- calls the `getMatrix()` method of the object called `Matrix`, or
- calls the `static` method `getMatrix()` of the `Matrix` class.

The method returns a 2D array of `int`, which is assigned to `mat`.

Comment: yeah, right.. Ugh how I didn't see it haha

Answer (score 2):

```
Matrix.getMatrix();
```

`Matrix` is the class name, and `getMatrix()` is a static method of `Matrix` class. The source code of it would be something like this:

```
public class Matrix
{
    // ...

    public static int[][] getMatrix()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In the program I got they didn't write the 'public static int[][] getMatrix()' method

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

> The Java programming language supports static methods as well as
>   static variables. Static methods, which have the static modifier in
>   their declarations, should be invoked with the class name, without the
>   need for creating an instance of the class, as in
>
> ClassName.methodName(args)

So `getMatrix()` is a *static* method of *Matrix class*.

I assume that `Matrix` is not an object since it begins with an upper-case (if you're following `Java` convention of course).

Answer (score 0):

[Matrix#getMatrix(int[] r,int[] c);](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/Matrix.html#getMatrix%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29)

> Get a submatrix.